# Как вывести значение которое получилось в результате последней итерации цикла через print

Tags: python

Всем, кто читает мой очень серьезный вопрос, привет!
(Мелкая монета для зарплаты . Напишите программу, которая вычисляет денежную
сумму, которую человек заработает в течение периода времени, если в первый день его
зарплата составит одну копейку, во второй день две копейки и каждый последующий
день будет удваиваться. Программа должна запросить у пользователя количество дней,
вывести таблицу, показывающую зарплату за каждый день, и затем показать заработную
плату до налоговых и прочих удержаний в конце периода. Итоговый результат должен
быть выведен в рублях, а не в количестве копеек.) Вот текст задачки

```
days = int(input('Введите количество дней, за которые вы получите зарплату: '))
salary = 0.01
day = 1
print("День \t Зарплата")
print("----------------")
for i in range(days):
    print (day, "\t", salary)
    salary*=2
    day +=1

print("На", days ,"день, зарплата составит")
```

Comment: После цикла распечайте `salary`.

Comment: Спасибо! сразу после публикации своего очень сурьезного вопроса допер сам, но все равно спасибо)